# Create a 1-element array from a random element in a String array

Tags: arrays, swift, return

I am trying to write a swift function that returns a single element array from a randomly-selected element of a String array (`allFruits`).

**Goal:**

```
let allFruits:[String] = ["Apples", "Oranges", "Pears", "Grapes", "Bananas"]

randomFruit = ["Apple"]
```

**My progress:**

```
let allFruits:[String] = ["Apples", "Oranges", "Pears", "Grapes", "Bananas"]

func randomFruit(arraySource:[String]) -> [String]{
    let randomItem = arraySource.randomElement()
    var singleArray:[String] = []
    return singleArray.append(contentsOf: randomItem)
}
```

I would then call this with `randomFruit(arraySource: allFruits)` to get ["Pears"]

The above return statement is giving me the error of:

> Cannot convert return expression of type '()' to return type
> '[String]'

**How can I return a random 1-element array from `allFruits`?**

Comment: `return singleArray.append(contentsOf: randomItem)`-> `singleArray.append(contentsOf: randomItem); return singleArray`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`randomItem` in your code is an optional since `.randomElement` can return `nil`. This is confusing the `.append()` call at the end.  The following should solve that issue.

```
func randomFruit(arraySource:[String]) -> [String]{
    if let item = arraySource.randomElement() {
        return [item]
    } else {
        return []
    }
}
```